# OpenOCD for NRF51 simultaneously with Ac6 plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, stm32, openocd, nrf51

I use **Eclipse Neon** with **Ac6** plugin for STM32. All works perfectly.

But now I need to work with **NRF51 MCU** and I can't find "clean" **OpenOCD** config in Debug configuration.

And I can't install it in New Software because another (from plugin) is installed.

I was trying to use config from plugin, but it is not working.

Are there any ability to install "clean" OpenOCD simultaneously with Ac6 plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not like messing in one eclipse configuration. Personally I just install another fresh copy of the eclipse, and configure it for the particular toolchain and hardware. Disk space is cheap :) and and least I do damage already configured ones. It saves me a lots of time.

Comment: Not, when you have 120 Gb SSD.